# How to Call Js(client side controller) into Helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

How can i call JS(client side controller) function into helper js function. Please show me the code. Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Danryl,

A Sample Code below.

```
<aura:component >
    <ui:outputText aura:Id="Hello" value=""/>
    <ui:button label="Click" press="{!c.Click}"/>
</aura:component>
```

//Controller

```
({
    Click : function(component, event, helper)
    {

        helper.helperMethod(component,event,sum);
    }
})
```

//Helper

```
({
    helperMethod : function(component,sum) 
    {
        var hello=component.find("Hello");
        hello.set("v.value","New Value !!!")

    }
})
```

As ankuli suggested, refer the trailhead document.

Comment: Please check if you have idea about this.

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88770/putting-a-field-values-of-an-object-using-apex

Comment: Hope you can help me in this problem http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89252/how-to-swap-2-different-component-views-in-lightning?noredirect=1#comment118290_89252

Answer (score 0):

you can call helper js method from client side controller but reverse is not defined anywhere.
`helper.callMethodOfClinetSideCotnroller(component, parameter1);`

Comment: Where can we Study this one.. will you give me a tutorial link for that so that i can deeply understand and study how to use helper . Thank you I really appreciate your will to help.

Comment: You can use Trail head which will give you knowledge very quickly. and if you want go through deep into lightning. this link is useful https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf

Comment: Will you give me an example of code that will use a helper, JS( client side controller),apex(server side controller) , and aura componet. Please ..