# Putting a field values of an object using Apex

Tags: apex

The aim of this code is to set a value for the booker__c field in Ticket__c object. I am getting an error of **Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List**. All the Names returned to the getContactBooker() funtion will put in the Booker__c fields in Ticket__c. For Example The getContactBooker() will returned a list values of{john,martin,hannah}, These values will be put into the Booker__c field in Ticket__c so that when i call the **newTicketList()** it will return the {john,martin,hannah} values when i want to access the Booker__c field.

HERE IS MY CODE. IS THIS THE RIGHT WAY OF PUTTING A NEW VALUES

```
@AuraEnabled
Public Static List<Ticket__c> newTicketList(String textsearch,String EventName,String FieldSearch){
    List<Contact> j = getContactBooker(textsearch,EventName,FieldSearch);
    List<String> newids = new List<String>();
    for(integer i=0; i<j.size(); i++)
    {
        newids.add(j[i].Name);
    }
    List<Ticket__c> values = new List<Ticket__c>();
    for(integer i = 0; i< newids.size(); i++){
    values.Booker__c = newids[i];<--------ERROR POINTS HERE
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Booker__c` is the name of a field on your `Ticket__c` object.

The variable `values` is a list of tickets and not an individual ticket. What it looks like you want to do is create a new ticket for each value in the `newids` list and add it to the `values` list. You could try this:

```
@AuraEnabled
Public Static List<ReturnValues> newTicketList(String textsearch,String EventName,String FieldSearch){
    List<Contact> j = getContactBooker(textsearch,EventName,FieldSearch);
    List<String> newids = new List<String>();
    for(integer i=0; i<j.size(); i++) {
        newids.add(j[i].Name);
    }
    List<ReturnValues> values = new List<ReturnValues>();
    for(integer i = 0; i< newids.size(); i++){
        ReturnValues rv = new ReturnValues();
        rv.BookerName = newids[i];
        // rv.TicketHolderName = /*put name here*/
        // rv.TicketInformation = new Ticket__c(/*fieldname = fieldvalue, ...*/);
        values.add(rv);
    }
    return values;
}

public class ReturnValues{
    @AuraEnabled public String BookerName {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String TicketHolderName {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Ticket__c TicketInformation {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: yes. You get it.. But your code gives me null value

Comment: When i System.debug the values. It says **Invalid ID**

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio ah, it must be that Booker__c is a look-up to Contact and not a text field.

Comment: yes .. booker is a lookup of the Contact.. its not a textfield but i get a null value

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio if you want to display the name of the booker, you have a few options. You could 1 add it as a field on Contact, 2 change the return type of the function to a wrapper class that contains all of the information that you want to send to the app, 3 if you just need the name and aren't passing back anything else, you could just change the return type to be a `list<String>`

Comment: I created a lookup field in Ticket__c called Booker__c. My problem is When i retrieve the Ticket__c field values. The Booker__c field show ID and what i want is to show the name of the contact not an ID .. thats why i came up into this code. I am very new in salesforce i dont know what to do. haha

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio do you just want the booker name, or do you have other ticket information that you want to pass back?

Comment: What i need to display in the Ticket__c object is the Booker__c, Ticket__Holder__c and Ticket__ID__c, Both two field are lookup to the contact. So i decided to query the name using the ids of the booker and the ticketholder after getting the names. I am planning to make a new values for booker and ticket holder and i will return it into Ticket__c list. but im struggling

Comment: I want the ticket informations also.

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio I've edited my answer. This should help get you set up.

Comment: **rv.TicketInformation = new Ticket__c(Ticket_ID__c = ticket[i]);** gettting me an error of **Field is not writeable: Ticket__c.Ticket_ID__c**

Comment: I solve the error Thankyou Martin . You are awesome

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio excellent! glad I could help.

Comment: You help me twice and maybe more and more and more .... hahaha :D

Comment: Hope you can help this problem. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89252/how-to-swap-2-different-component-views-in-lightning?noredirect=1#comment118290_89252

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio I just posted something recently that is similar to what you are trying to do. There have been a lot of questions about lightning component navigation recently and I don't know if there is an established best way to do it. If you are still looking for ideas, you might want to check this out: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66954/how-to-navigate-from-one-lightning-component-to-another-lightning-component/89312#89312

Comment: Hi martin .. I will look your post tommorow .. i hope it will solve my problem

Comment: I dont see any changing of view @Martin. Got me an output of all the list element has a button Go of their side. Please test your code

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio okay, what happened when you pushed go? Did it take you to the list of opportunities? I might have missed something when copying to this site.

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio also make sure the namespace gets changed to fit your org.

Comment: yes.i already changed the namespace.. can you please try the code ? i am trying to find out whats the problem for this. please do so.

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio It sounds like there is an issue with the event being fired. When you click on go, is there a warning message that appears on the screen?

Comment: Nothing.. did you check this code before you post ?.. i guess the issue is in the component client side controller. There is no value passed to the event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27411/discussion-between-martin-and-danryl-tigol-carpio).

Comment: No it has value passed into the event but the ato function in the client side controller of the app not executed. i dont know what's wrong

Comment: MAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRTTTTTTTTTTIIIIIIIIIN ! Why is it Sometimes this line of code wont work

    AddToggle : function(component, event, helper) {
        var listeve = component.get("v.listval");
        var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:SelectEvent");
        myEvent.setParams({"sevent":  listeve});
        myEvent.fire();
    }

Comment: I still get the same problem.. event fired but the function of the JS wont work

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio I guess some other things you could check are: 1. the type of the event should be `"APPLICATION"` and 2. the name of the event file should be `SelectEvent.evt` (the name attribute of the registered event is only relevant for COMPONENT events)

Comment: I solve it :) thankyou.. I dont apply your concept martin sorry. In my code i apply Toggle classes . its more faster as i thought

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio what was the problem then? Did you ever get the events to work?

Comment: yeah.. i already solve the event firing to work.. thanks to you.. i understand deeply the flow

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio nice! glad to help.